# How to send data to node js server with ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm trying to read data sent to node.js server.

Client side:

```
const sendToDB =(date)=> {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var d = JSON.stringify(date);
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(d);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "api/info", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send(d);
}
```

and the server:

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  req.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(req.body.date);
  });
  res.end();
});
server.listen(3001);
```

how to receive data sent with xhttp.send(d) in node js server ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
      if(req.method == "POST"){       
           var clientData = '';
           req.on('data', function (chunk) {
                clientData+=chunk;
           });
           req.on('end',function(){
                console.log(JSON.parse(clientData));
           })
      }
      res.end();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the header `"Content-Type", "application/json"` as you send some json data.
make sure you send a such an object :

```
{
  date: {
    foo: bar
  }
}
```

as your server is expecting it in the body `req.body.date`